# Select many to many using function count()

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have many to many relationships and i try to find User which has a minimum requests im my subs table but i can't understand how i can do it.

Could you please clarify how i can do it

my Models are:

```
    subs = db.Table('subs',
                db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                db.Column('request_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'))
                )

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    role = db.Column(db.String(120))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(120))
    requests = db.relationship('Request', secondary=subs,
                               backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    post = db.relationship('Posts', backref = 'user', lazy = 'dynamic')
    request = db.relationship('Request', backref='user', lazy = 'dynamic')
    is_active = db.Column(db.String(120))


class Request(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'request'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org = db.Column(db.String(120))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default= datetime.utcnow)
    cost_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    update_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow())
    diff_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    feedback = db.Column(db.Text, default=update_time)
    comment = db.relationship('Posts', backref = 'request', lazy='dynamic')
    rate_idea = db.Column(db.Integer)
    new = db.Column(db.Text)
    cost_buyer = db.relationship('Costs', backref = 'request', lazy='dynamic')
    status = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('status.id'))
```

For example:

```
User1.requests = [Request_1, 'Request_2, Request_3]
User2.requests = [Request_2, Request_3]
```

When somebody do a new Request i need to clarify firstly which user has a minimum requests from all of users and then put this request to him.

```
New_request = Request(org = 'TEST')
```

In this case User2 must add this New_request to his own User.requests so the final result must be

```
User1.requests = [Request_1, 'Request_2, Request_3]

User2.requests = [Request_2, Request_3, New_request]
```

i want to do query something like this, but what is the right and simple  solution for this i don't know and i want to know:

```
db.query.filter(min(len(User.requests))
```

Comment: You should join User with User.requests, then do `groupby`, use `func.count()`, order by this expression and finally use `limit(1)` to get only one user.

Comment: Dear Mikhail could you please provide full request if possible.  I have no idea how to use groupby. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. But I suggest you to check the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).

```
from sqlalchemy import func
db.query(User.id, func.count())
    .outerjoin(User.requests)
    .group_by(User.id)
    .order_by(func.count())
    .limit(1)
```